# Servlet not found in Intellij

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

I trying to run my jsp page along with a servlet. The Servlet is not found when I try to call it via url

http://localhost:8080/StudentServlet 
I get a 404 error saying:

> "requested resource not available".

I am also trying to call it via a Form. When I click submit, its not recognised either producing same error.

Read answers here asking to use Maven or set up mapping via web.xml. From my understanding, setting up via web.xml is the old way and the new way is to set up name on the servlet which I have. Unsure what I am doing wrong.

I am not using and build tool and just starting up my Tomcat server used locally to run jsp pages which works. But Servlets are not recognised. Added screenshot for project structure in case something is wrong there.

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet(name = "StudentServlet")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body>");

        out.println("<h3>Student name is:" +
                request.getParameter("firstname") +
                " " +
                request.getParameter("lastname") +
                "</h3>");

        out.println("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="StudentServlet" method="get">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

Comment: Your URL is wrong.

Comment: @duffymo Tried url http://localhost:8080/servletdemo/StudentServlet which throws same error. What should the url be?

Comment: What is the name of your WAR file?  What domain did you tell IntelliJ to use?

Comment: @duffymo I don't have a war file. Everytime I run the tomcat server, it displays a message saying "war exploded" and opens up the localhost page in the url. I didn't set any domain.

Comment: What `web.xml` version is used?

Comment: @CrazyCoder The version is 3.1

Comment: Did you try specifying `value` or `urlPattern` attributes for the `@WebServlet` annotation?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It works with urlPatterns. Still confused as to why assigning name doesn't work. Also any changes in urlPatterns requires a server restart unlike jsp where I could make hot updates.

Comment: You can use `@WebServlet("/StudentServlet")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WebServlet documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) states the following:

> At least one URL pattern MUST be declared in either the `value` or `urlPattern` attribute of the annotation, but not both.

You can just use the following:

```
@WebServlet("/StudentServlet")
```

or this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "StudentServlet", urlPatterns={"/StudentServlet"})
```

or this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "StudentServlet", value="/StudentServlet")
```

> The `value` attribute is recommended for use when the URL pattern is the only attribute being set, otherwise the `urlPattern` attribute should be used.

Comment: It works now thanks. Unfortunately seems a server reset needed every time a change is made on the java file. No hot change.

Comment: Check [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html), all the changes supported by Java HotSwap will not require redeployment or server restart (you can change method body, but you can't delete or add methods). For more advanced HotSwap you can use DCEVM or JRebel.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Give a Context Path in the your Form action. This way, it will automatically find your Servlet's path. For example

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sampleServlet">
```

> Also, write the URL pattern "/" in the @WebServlet(name =
>   "/StudentServlet") This annotation indicates that the URL pattern
>   /StudentServlet follows the context root.
>
> Plus,
>   give the the Context Root in your localhost
>   eg: http://localhost:8080/ContextRoot/StudentServlet

Comment: Tried the above and edited answer. Still getting same error. Restarted server and no difference.

Comment: Did you try the exact address? eg: http://localhost:8080/ContextRoot/StudentServlet where ContextRoot is the name of the Web Project (by Default) or if you gave some other name then you need to put that name

Comment: Project name is servletdemo as you can see in the project structure. Thus calling:  localhost:8080/servletdemo/StudentServlet giving same error.

Comment: Are you trying to visit a Home Page when you run the Project? If so, then you are missing a Startup Page that will be opened when you run the project. For example, the index.jsp as you have in the project, I hope it is added in the web.xml file as: <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Comment: I do not have issue with viewing jsp page. I did not set up web.xml file but localhost:8080 defaults to the index.jsp page. The issue is with servlets.

Comment: Are you able to view the index.jsp page when you visit the localhost?

Comment: Yes I am able to view it.